# Complete Info for Setting Up SubSonic 3 with Oracle

Tags: subsonic3

I'm looking for the **complete** steps for setting up SubSonic 3 with **Oracle** 10g.
I see a lot of pieces out there, but no clear list.

**Please correct me where I'm wrong:**

1. Create Class Library (.net 3.5)
2. create an app.config with a valid connectionString to your db
3. Download the latest version of SubSonic 3 (today it's SubSonic_3.0.0.4)
4. add the dll SubSonic.Core.dll as a reference
5. Go to: [SubSonic-3.0-Templates  / TemplateProviders](http://github.com/stimms/SubSonic-3.0-Templates/tree/master/TemplateProviders/)  and get 3 files: Oracle.ttinclude       OracleDataProvider.ttinclude        Settings.ttinclude
6. find the folder:  SubSonic 3.xxx\T4 Templates\ActiveRecord
7. copy over the 3 files from step 4 into this folder
8. update: Settings.ttinclude to have your namespace and connection string
9. create a folder in your project called /Model/
10. drag and drop the files, from step 7, into this folder
11. cross your fingers
12. I get error:

> Error 2   Compiling transformation: The
>   name 'CleanUp' does not exist in the
>   current context   c:\Subversion
>   Store\project\Models\SQLServer.ttinclude

Or should I instead download: [mabraham1 / LINQ2Oracle](http://github.com/mabraham1/LINQ2Oracle)
I do not see any documentation on this site about how to get up and running.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Hi Joel, I could not find support on this. After burning 2-3 days I gave up. I would recommend perhaps trying Telerik ORM.